# Filter common products from two or more categories

Tags: magento-1.9, category, filter, product-collection, magento-1.9.2.1

I need to **merge two or more categories products and filter the common products from the collection.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it.

First, **get the products ids from one category**:

```
$productCollection1 = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                       ->addCategoryFilter($categoryId1)
                       ->getAllIds();
```

Then **get the products ids from the second category**:

```
$productCollection2 = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                       ->addCategoryFilter($categoryId2)
                       ->getAllIds();
```

Then you can **intersect the two arrays of product ids to be sure you get the product ids that are available in both categories**:

```
$finalProductIds = array_intersect($productCollection1, $productCollection2);
```

Finally, if you need to get every detail about those products y**ou can create a new collection based on the final array**:

```
$finalProductCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                          ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $finalProductIds));
```